# Is there a more recent data dump then the one from Sep 2011?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump

The only source I can find for the announcements of the quarterly public data dumps is [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/). The latest one is from September 2011, i.e. 1.5 years ago. Shouldn't we have had many more since then? Are they announced somewhere else now, or did StackExchange change the data dump release frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, OK, I get it now, they're [here](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump), when I first saw that site I intuitively clicked the large "Stack Exchange Data Dump" link at the top, but the data dumps ordered by date are actually under "Content" on the right hand side... I feel dumb.